# How to pass Dynamic Class type for a Generic method in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Generic method

```
JsonMapper.ToObject<>(jsonString);
```

but here i want to pass the Generic type to the method, which I have in a String, so how can I pass the class type from String to this methods generic type?

In java i can use

```
Class.forName("");
```

but in C# how should I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding you correctly, but in c# with generics, you pass a type in the `<>`  bit of any generic methods.

Comment: @mituw16 indeed, but you don't pass a runtime `Type` instance. In this case it looks like the user will have a `Type`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no nice way of mixing reflection and generics; they *are not friends*. You could use `MakeGenericMethod` etc, but then you are doing *a lot of things* manually.

Frankly, my advice here is: don't design tools like this to use a generic API. Use a non-generic `Type`-based API. You can always *re-expose* it as generics:

```
public T Foo<T>(...) { return (T) Foo(typeof(T), ...); }

public object Foo(Type type, ...) {
    // the actual code
}
```

You **can** do the exact reverse - via `MakeGenericMethod` and `Invoke` - but it is less efficient and less flexible.

To get a `Type` from a `string`, see `Type.GetType(string)` and `assembly.GetType(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
MethodInfo method = (from x in typeof(JsonMapper).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                     where x.Name == "ToObject" && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                     let pars = x.GetParameters()
                     where pars.Length == 1 && pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                     select x).Single();

// Your generic type
Type type = Type.GetType("System.String");

MethodInfo method2 = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

// Your input
string jsonString = "Hello";

object result = method2.Invoke(null, new object[] { jsonString });
```

This if `ToObject<>` is `static` and has a signature like:

```
public static T ToObject<T>(string input)
```

Comment: im sorry , what is X in here?

Comment: Which `x`? The one in the LINQ expression?